# Impala can not drop external table

Tags: sql, hdfs, cloudera-cdh, impala

I create a external table with a wrong(non-exists) path :

```
create external table IF NOT EXISTS ds_user_id_csv
(
    type string,
    imei string,
    imsi string,
    idfa string,
    msisdn string,
    mac string
)
PARTITIONED BY(prov string,day string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
stored as textfile
LOCATION 'hdfs://cdh0:8020/user/hive/warehouse/test.db/ds_user_id';
```

And I can not drop the table:

```
[cdh1:21000] > drop table ds_user_id_csv
         > ;
Query: drop table ds_user_id_csv
ERROR:
ImpalaRuntimeException: Error making 'dropTable' RPC to Hive Metastore:
CAUSED BY: MetaException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://cdh0:8020/user/hive/warehouse/test.db/ds_user_id, expected: hdfs://nameservice1
```

So how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you change the location? `ALTER TABLE name ds_user_id_csv SET LOCATION '{new location}';`

Comment: Thank you very much ! I changed location and I finally delete it.@Dudu Markovitz

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to change the location

```
ALTER TABLE name ds_user_id_csv SET LOCATION '{new location}';
```